# How to bind properly and ObservableCollection to a Custom Control property?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created a Custom Control with some properties to bind, in my case just to make visible or not the control itself and the other one to pass a previous populated ObservableCollection to create the control content.

First one works perfectly but the ObservableCollection is not being correctly bound even if I added it in the XAML.

This is what I got when I try to iterate it inside queue control after making it visible:

https://i.imgur.com/dddFoWu.png

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

This is my property:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty ContractsListProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ContractList), typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(PrivacyControl), new ObservableCollection<object>(), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ContractListPropertyChangedDelegate);
```

```cs
public ObservableCollection<object> ContractList 
{
            get => 
(ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ContractsListProperty);
            set => SetValue(ContractsListProperty, value);
}
```

This is my control in XAML:

```xml
<controls:PrivacyControl IsPrivacyVisible="{Binding IsPrivacyStackVisible}" ContractList="{Binding CardsAndLoansList}" />
```

EDITED:

This is my VM where I check and add Cards/Loans to the `ObservableCollection<object>`, "CardsAndLoans" is also initialized in the ctor.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<object> cardsAndLoansList;
public ObservableCollection<object> CardsAndLoansList
{
get => cardsAndLoansList;
set { cardsAndLoansList = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}

private async Task InitUserInfoAndPrivacy()
{
            CardsAndLoansList.Clear();

            await InitUserInformation();

            var hasLoans = GlobalSettings.Loans.NotNullOrEmpty();
            if (hasLoans)
            {
                foreach (var loan in GlobalSettings.Loans)
                    CardsAndLoansList.Add(loan);
            }

            ExampleList = CardsAndLoansList.ToList(); //<=== This is from an another try with List<obj>. 

            IsPrivacyStackVisible = UserData.ContractList.NotNullOrEmpty() || hasLoans;
}
```

Comment: What's the `BindingContext`of the control? Does it have a property called "CardsAndLoansList" of type `ObservableCollection<object>`? Please remember to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) when asking a question.

Comment: The `BindingContext` at the moment the control is created is my ViewModel, where I populate the property "CardsAndLoansList" which is an `ObservableCollection<object>`.

I populate this list using `CardsAndLoansList.Add(x)`. I tried with a simple `List<object>` too with same result.

Comment: Could you share the code where declare the `CardsAndLoansList` and where you assign it?

Comment: @Knoop sure, I just updated the question with some VM lines. Hope it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo. The `BindableProperty` is called `ContractsListProperty` and the property itself is called `ContractList` (missing an s). Change this to `ContractsList` and it should work (the `BindableProperty` name has to be the name of the property + "Property")

Hope this helps

Comment: oh my... that's it! Didn't know that has to be exactly the same. Could never notice it. TY!

Comment: Yeah exactly why this is required I don't know (since you already pass the name of the property to the BindableProperty constructor) but for some reason it has to match. Anyway you're welcome! Good luck with the project:-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to your custom control and then add the source reference to the binding properties in the Xaml. For example,

top xaml tag should have name,

```
<ContentView
xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Sample.Controls.List"
         x:Name="listControl">
```

and then when binding the property, add the source reference like below,

```
<ListView  IsVisible="{Binding IsPrivacyVisible, Source={x:Reference listControl}}" ItemSource="{Binding ContractList, Source={x:Reference listControl}}" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Abdul Gani, but doesn't work. I inherited this project and saw they are using your solution for other elements, but doesn't solve my issue.